# Solr not searching for words ending in "e"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, solr

I'm new to Solr and I'm facing a weird problem.

When I search words ending in "e", it always returns no results. For example:

Let's suppose there is a record "QWERTY" on the DB.
When the search word is "QWERT", it returns the record "QWERTY".
When the search word is "QWERTY", it returns the record "QWERTY". (correct)

Let's suppose there is a record "ABCDE" on the DB.
When the search word is "ABCD", it returns the record "ABCDE".
When the search word is "ABCDE", it returns nothing!!

I found some problems related with "solr ignores last letter" and some stuff like this, but didn't find something related to this.

I'm using Solr 0.9.2.2 (3 years project), Rails 3.2.2, Apache 2.2.22 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Any ideas??

Thank you!

--Edit--
Schema:
http://www.speedyshare.com/khdcr/schema.xml

Query:
query_string = ("%" + params[:nome] + "%").upcase
    produto_busca = Estoque::Produto.of(current_empresa).where("nome LIKE ? or est_produtos.nome_fantasia LIKE ? ", query_string, query_string).order("nome ASC")

There are several queries with the same problem. This one is just an example.

Comment: Need Solr schema.xml and the query you are using

Comment: I've edited the post with the query and schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several weeks, I found the solution to this problem.

Lucene Solr has a filter called Stemming. This filter basically captures the "root" of the words. It removes some letters to do it, for example:

- Consist -> Consist
- Consisted -> Consist
- Consisting -> Consist
  And so on... (Reference http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html)

The key points about my system are:

- Language: Portuguese
- Not indexing full text, just some words.

The solution was to remove Stemming from Solr Schema (solr/conf/schema.xml):

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type='index'>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The new code basically separate the words by "white spaces", change special characteres to regular ones (á -> a), put all letters to lowercase (Aaa -> aaa) and uses NGram filter (abc -> ab bc abc ...).

(References: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions)

Hope this helps...

Ps: There are versions of Stemming to several languages.